# Hibernate 2LC and Query cache with infinispan

Tags: hibernate, infinispan

I am using hibernate4 and have configured 2LC and query cache with infinispan4. I can see in JVisualVM Mbean tab that my application uses 2LC as i can see hit count for various configured caches increased, but i am not able to see any activity on query cache side, it does not get hits, what i can see is only miss count increasing. I tried replacing several HQL queries with criteria queries to make them eligible for query cache, but seems to be not working. I have configured hibernate.cache.use_query_cache property to true and also updated code to cache the queries.What could be the reason for this not working ?

Comment: Adding further, i have enabled H2LC logs and took them in separate log file.Looking at the logs it says "Starting query cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache", but in JVisualVm MBeans tab under infinispan cache node, i am not able to see any cache with the above specified name. Its wearied !

Comment: I'd suggest enabling TRACE logging for `org.hibernate.cache.infinispan` and `org.infinispan` package, and see what's going on with the query cache. Remember to call `setCacheable` on the queries too.

Comment: Thanks Galder, i did that too and it seems that hibernate is going to query cache for look up but returns with no results from cache.I have called setCacheable() where ever applicable.strange !

Comment: hardik, got to dig a bit further :). Why are there no results in the cache? Were these results stored at all? Where they removed somehow? Expiration of some sort?...etc

Comment: Any news on this @hardik?

Comment: sadly, no news @Konstantin